# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results - Mean Net Score: 0.6

- [Denoting end of family line, no children in GED and other records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7844/denoting-end-of-family-line-no-children-in-ged-and-other-records)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does "Full Baptist Communion" indicate?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/what-does-full-baptist-communion-indicate)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Did Edward Buten change his name from Edward Bulen?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/did-edward-buten-change-his-name-from-edward-bulen)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Determining location/address of Robert John Steven Sellers in 1900 from Sands and Macdougall Directory for South Australia?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/determining-location-address-of-robert-john-steven-sellers-in-1900-from-sands-an)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Finding evidence for Daniel Denehy and Ellen Connors in 19th Century Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/finding-evidence-for-daniel-denehy-and-ellen-connors-in-19th-century-wales)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What does "Containing by Estimation Seven Days' Work" mean in 1810 Land Auction advertisement?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/what-does-containing-by-estimation-seven-days-work-mean-in-1810-land-auction)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to identify individual family members / household size on early US Censuses Pre-1830 NY & PA?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7856/how-to-identify-individual-family-members-household-size-on-early-us-censuses)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Find Austrian vital records?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/find-austrian-vital-records)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What happened to Nathan Stein and Sarah Goldberg Stein who were living in London 1897?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-happened-to-nathan-stein-and-sarah-goldberg-stein-who-were-living-in-london)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Middle name or two first names?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7841/middle-name-or-two-first-names)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

The Mean Net Score was calculated by adding the ten Net Scores (4, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, -2, -2, -2) and dividing the total by 10

Answer (score 3):

I thought the overall quality of both Questions and Answers in this Site Review was higher than in previous reviews.

With regard to site health I would like to see more people asking more questions in order to benefit from the expertise available.